# PSU died, is hard drive fried? Are other components damaged?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply

After discovering and replacing my dead PSU, I was able to boot back into Windows. Everything seems to be working fine, however, one hard drive is not. Windows 7 says that this SATA hard drive needs to be formatted before it can work. Can the data be recovered? Also, is there a way to check the integrity of the other components of my computer or assume they will work fine?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider downloading the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), a collection of 100+ utilities to run from CD on bootup that can evaluate your hardware.  I routeinly use it to check memory (MemTest86+) as well as hard drives as they have manufacturer specific tools from Western Digital, Seagate, and others.

I'm fuzzy what other hardware it would help you evaluate, but its a very useful tool for someone in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

try giving [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a shot on the  drive

Comment: I tried testdisk. It thinks the drive is only about 30 megs large, in reality its 1TB. It was able to see the drive is really 1 TB but wasn't able to recover the data. Am I missing something?

Comment: You said "It thinks the drive is only about 30 megs large, in reality its 1TB. It was able to see the drive is really 1 TB", which is a contradiction. Does it report the disk as 30 MB or 1 TB?

Comment: Reports it as 33MB - CHS 64 16 63, but it also says "Warning: Bad ending head (CHS and LBA don't match)". On the next screen it says: "The harddisk (33 MB / 31 MiB) seems too small! (<1000 GB / 931 GiB) Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection... Hint: update Windows to support LBA48 (minimum: W2K SP4 or XP SP1)". Then says the following partition can't be recovered, listing the partition.

Comment: That sounds like the BIOS detection of the drive no longer works properly, but the drive *might* be OK.